# Проблема с дочерней темой Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, хук

Имеется тема Impreza, нужно подключить файл дочерней темы в подпапке 
/framework/functions/widget_areas.php

хочу убрать теги h3 из виджетов.

Установлен WP 4.9.1, какой хук можно применить чтобы внести изменения в дочернюю тему в этом файле с подпапками?

Comment: не помогает решение.
Желательно подключить тот файл widget_areas.php тк если заменить h3 на h2 в нем в родительской теме, то все работает.
Может кто знает все таки какой хук применить для подключения файла к дочерней теме?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте удалить, а затем заново зарегистрировать сайдбар с нужными параметрами.

```
function replace_some_widgets(){
    unregister_sidebar( 'impreza-sidebar' );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'theme-slug' ),
        'id' => 'impreza-sidebar',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'theme-slug' ),
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</li>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'replace_some_widgets', 11 );
```

Код поместить в файл functions.php дочерней темы. Не забудьте заменить ID сайдбара на свой.